# How to edit the source code of joomla individual pages

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I have a Joomla site, and I want to remove a the footer div from a page without it affecting it on the other pages. Please is there a way I can do it.

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options - you should be able to set additional CSS on that article to hide the particular footer div for that one individual page without issue.

Additionally you could install a plugin like Sourcerer that allows for PHP coding directly into articles in Joomla! (which comes in REALLY handy!); then you could remove it programmatically as well if necessarily.

Alternatively - you could create a template override for that particular template/page and edit the PHP there to reflect appropriate course of action for that URL/Page.

I tried to list them in order of easiest to most difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not a clean method to hide template-elements by using CSS (display:none). And for your intension you dont´t need a external plugin.
Try a page-option in your template *index.php*.
First - to get page-options work:

```
    <?php $pageoption1 = JRequest::getVar( 'Itemid', '' ); $pageoption2 = JRequest::getVar( 'page', '' ); $pageoption3 = JRequest::getVar( 'option', '' ); ?>
```

And further:

```
        <?php if ($pageoption1 == '1') { ?>
This text will be visible only in the page with Menu Item ID 1
<?php } ?>
```

This works lately in Joomla 2.5.X - for newer version i think it will also work fine.